# function 'is null' in twig not working

Tags: symfony, twig

I have develop a symfony website application.

I use a function 'is null' to check if my column has a null value or not.
but it is not work.

this is the screenshot for
[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xncqI.png)

and this is my code

```
<div class="col-md-9">
   {% if info_user.company_date_created is null %}
     <p>-</p>
   {% else %}
      <p style="text-transform: uppercase">{{ info_user.company_date_created }}</p>
   {% endif %}
</div>
```

**NB : i left my *company_date_created* column with null value in database to test if my code work for null value or not**

Comment: What is `info_user`?

Comment: that is the array

Comment: Why on the screenshot it says it's a query builder then?

Comment: `return $app['twig']->render('subsector/detail-profile.html.twig', ['info_user' => $userInfo]);`

this is my code to call twig template

Comment: What is `$userInfo`?

Comment: `$id = $request->get('id',0);
 $userInfo = User::find($id);`
.. 
it works with not null column

Comment: `var_dump($userInfo);`

Comment: `'company_date_created' => null` .. so i wanna create a view if this null or not, but the problem, twig giving me error

Comment: Try `{% if info_user.company_date_created == null %}`

Comment: same error @Chausser

Comment: `var_dump($userInfo['company_date_created']);` ? What type the `$userInfo` is? Are you sure it is an array?

Comment: Can you add your entity descriptor for that field, to the question?

Comment: it returns `null`

Comment: And the relevant parts of the Query builder you are using

Comment: @Chausser what was that ?

Comment: @JimmyFish Your `User` entity file, it seems like it cant find the column you are looking for.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/zrQaK

Comment: this error show in every column with null value

Comment: ups it solved when i try `$userInfo = User::find($id)->getAttributes();`

Comment: So it was not an array initially. Lesson learned: check not guess.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, null and undefined are different values. If you were working with an ArrayCollection then it would not be a problem, but I think you are working with common arrays.

To check if some index is defined inside an array, Twig has a function called [defined](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html). I think you only need to change **is null** to **is defined**.

I'm assuming also that you have only an array with plane items. Are you working with dehydrated or hydrated values?

Answer (score 0):

Add a [`is defined`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html) condition:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
   {% if info_user.company_date_created is defined and info_user.company_date_created is null %}
     <p>-</p>
   {% else %}
      <p style="text-transform: uppercase">{{ info_user.company_date_created }}</p>
   {% endif %}
</div>
```